# UWP App can't connect to MongoDB when packed for deploy

Tags: c#, mongodb, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app using C# and the MongoDB connection works perfectly in the development computer. When I tried to export and install it in a different desktop it did not work.

I have some peculiarities on the target computer: no internet and no Visual Studio. I export my app, using the "Create App Packages" on Visual Studio, install all dependencies in the target desktop, and install the App.

Everything works, but the MongoDB Connection. When it tries to connect to the MongoDB Serve (local installation on target computer), it can't connect and I receive a timeout error.

What I know so far:

- Nothing is wrong with the MongoDB installation, I can connect to it from the Mongo Compass and from a working 'App' from a different computer.
- When I downloaded the Remote Debug Tools from Visual Studio, I got a message "installing missing libraries", and it started working (I had to get a new windows installation to reproduce the problem, without remote debugging).
- I already tried to install the missing NuGet packages (MongoDB.Driver, MongoDB.Bson and MongoDB.Driver.Core) on the target computer, but it did not seem to change anything.
- Firewall is disabled.
- All permissions were added to the UWP app.
- Tried to connect without the loopback, but also did not work **(EDIT)**

Target windows version: 1809

MongoDB Packages version: 2.9.2

Visual Studio: 17

```cs
_client = new MongoClient(connectString);
_db = _client.GetDatabase(database);

BsonDocument doc = _instance._db.RunCommand((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}");
IsConnected = doc["ok"] == 1;
Logger.Log("[MONGO] Connected to MongoDB");
```

Error message: "A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector...."

Comment: Hi Lucas, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897774/connecting-two-local-uwp-apps-on-same-machine. I think your problem is the same

Comment: Thank you very much, that might be the problem! On Monday I will try it.

Comment: @thezapper, thank you for your replay. Unfortunately it did not work :(

Comment: Any other ideias?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for 2 days on that so I'm going to leave the answer here :

```
checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=UWPAppPackageName
```

After trying basically the same things that Lucas did and more :

- Disabling the firewall
- Granting permission on the UWP app
- Separating the client instantiation and the "getDatabase" call
- Creating the smallest UWP app that connects with MongoDB with the c# driver
- Testing to connect with another app (nodejs)

I kept having the error with the UWP app only when creating a package.

```
Exception: System.TimeoutException Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core Message: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector
```

I saw Lucas's topic and thought to myself "nah" can't be the loopback if he didn't manage to make it work. But hours after that I decided to try it anyway and checked the link "thezapper" provided. But it seems that the command provided in the answer doesn't have the correct argument. Fortunately, I had some previous history with the command (for card payment devices connexion) and I tried with the "-a" arg instead of "-d".

Note : If you're searching your UWP package name go to :

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\
```

Check the last installed package to find it. It could be a long ugly GUID like so:

```
89477457-1a2b-4474-94fc-b3ca50efdb96_5g1hdzhsabgzt
```